# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли тут запятая? Может, это какое-нибудь неразложимое сочетание?

**У меня есть(,)что почитать.**

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна, конечно.
А почему вдруг её тут ставить? "Что" здесь не является союзным словом. Если академики опять не персмотрели классификацию, то "что" здесь считает- местоименное существительное.

Сравните: "У меня есть книга почитать [в поезде]".

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. "Есть что почитать" - это грамматическая основа предложения

Comment: А поподробнее?

Comment: Мне кажется, "что почитать" (книга, газета...) - это подлежащее, ну а "есть" - сказуемое

Answer (score 0):

**Роберт Бернс. - М.: Правда, 1979. - 272 с., ил.**

В этой книге есть один примечательный пунктуационный факт:

> У которых есть, что есть, — те подчас не могут есть,
>
> А другие могут есть, да сидят без хлеба.
>
> А у нас тут есть, что есть, да при этом есть, чем есть, —
>
> Значит, нам благодарить остается небо!

(Обычно для доказательства какой-либо гипотезы в языкознании принято приводить факты из классических произведений. Это перевод С. Маршака.)

Comment: Если не трудно, поподробнее и попонятнее. Что за факт, чем он примечателен. Самое главное - какое отношение к вопросу имеет и каков ответ на вопрос дает.

Comment: Не трудно: это запятая перед "что" во фразе "есть, что есть", которая аналогична фразе в вопросе ("Есть (,) что почитать").

Answer (score -1):

Не нужна. Неразложимые сочетания, состоящие из глагола "есть", местоименного слова ("что", "где", "как", "куда" и т. д.) и инфинитива, не разделяются запятой.

Comment: Здесь нет неразложимого сочетания.
Во всяком случае - а обычном понимании термина.
Откуда вы вообще подобную мудрость почерпнули?

Comment: Понятно, с грамоты сплагиатили.
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_193
Уж сколько раз твердили миру, что безымянные грамотовские ответы - не насного лучше вики и гугла.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Выражение "есть что" является полностью законченным по смыслу выражением. Инфинитив "почитать" - тем более.